# Item checkeado en angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un formulario con un checkbox, en el cual yo lo marco o lo dejo desmarcado, lo guardo en mi base de datos y se guarda 0 o 1, dependiendo si lo e marcado o no, ahora quiero editar ese checkbox y que me aparezca pulsado si es 1 y sin pulsar si es 0, pero no consigo realizarlo.

`hojaingreso[0].pair` - Aquí está la información obtenida del checkbox guardado en la base de datos

```
<input *ngIf="hojaingreso?.length != 0" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hojaingreso[0].pair" [value]="hojaingreso[0].pair" [disabled]="modificar == false">
```

He probado con `[checked]="hojaingreso[0].pair == true"`

con  == 0, == 1 etc...

Si pongo el ngModel me aparece siempre checkeado independientemente si tiene 0 o 1 guardado en la base de datos.

**EDITO**

Probando, me e dado cuenta que el ngModel si en vez de llevar 0 o 1 lleva true o false funciona perfectamente, pero como puedo hacer para que al obtener los datos en angular ponga true si es 1 o false si es 0, ya que no es 1 campo checkbox lo que tengo, tendré unos 20.

Comment: Probaste con una comparación estricta??...es decir colocando === en vez de ==

Comment: Acabo de probar y nada...

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que el valor del campo "pair" es numérico? Si en lugar de 0 o 1, tienes "0" o "1" no te funcionará.

Comment: es boolean el campo

Comment: Es raro, debería funcionarte bien, en este ejemplo funciona y tan sólo he copiado el código tal y como lo has puesto tu. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yd9zzg

Comment: parece ser que tu problema esta en tus datos, ¿podrías mostrar como es ese objeto `hojaingreso`?

Comment: Como estas leyendo los datos? tengo la impresión de que al leer los datos desde la base de datos no los estas recibiendo bien en el componente, quizás lo estás haciendo con una función anónima y te falta un bind

Comment: Si te entiendo correctamente lo que estas queriendo es colocar multiples checkbox en tu formulario y quieres que cuando traigas todos los objetos del arreglo pase de tipo de dato number a boolean, cosa rara ya que en javascript se pueden comparar, pero si eso es lo que quieres la vista no es tu problema sino en el controlador, podrías agregar un handler que te pase el tipo de dato.

Answer (score 2):

En la clase crea una variable

```
inputChecked: boolean
```

Creas un **`if else`** con el cual validas lo que te devuelve la base de datos y si es **1** le asignas un `true` a la variable o si es **0** un `false`

En **input** debes pones así:

```
[checked]="inputChecked"
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes modificar el comportamiento con estas linea:

```
<input 

   (change)='valor = valor === 1 ? 0 : 1'
   type="checkbox"  [value]="valor"
   [checked]='valor === 1'
 >
```

Donde `valor: 0|1 = 0` y se modifica en cada evento `change` que se desencadena.

Te dejo un ejemplo [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9hi9e)